# Eclipse EMF model query with Python

Tags: python, eclipse, emf, eclipse-emf

I need to run a query on a model and get results on a EMF model with **Python** code.

Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Employee I tried to google it, there is no python library for this. Eclipse EMF Query (https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.emf.query) does what I want but I do know how to run it on python code.

Answer (score 0):

[PyEcore](https://pypi.org/project/pyecore/) might do the job but I have never tried it.

Comment: It does not have query feature.

Comment: Hi, PyEcore dev here. Indeed, there is no query engine yet, but that's definitely something that could be added and interesting for a lot of people. Feel free to open an issue in github to propose it!

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but take a look at this project: https://gitlab.com/eoq/py/pyeoq

It was discussed in [this](https://github.com/pyecore/pyecore/issues/48) issue of `pyecore`

Comment: Yea, I opened that issue